# How Can I protect all MATLAB files in a folder

Tags: matlab

I am building a toolbox using MATLAB, the toolbox contains a GUI developed using "guide" and some other functions. I wan to publish this toolbox but I want to keep my source code protected and secure. All the files are in a folder. There are a lot of files, I know that I can convert each file to .p extension but they are too many. Is there any quick and easy method to achieve this task.

Comment: why don't you just write a script to change the file extension on all of the files?

Answer (score 2):

From the help:

> pcode(fun1,...,funN) creates N P-files from the listed files. If any
>   inputs are folders, then MATLAB creates a P-file for every .m file the
>   folders contain.

Thus

```
pcode(folderWithYourToolboxFiles)
```

will do what you want.